# HTTP Error 404 - File or Directory not found

Tags: website

I am unable to visit this site http://www.novamov.com/. Whenever I go, it shows `HTTP Error 404 - File or Directory not found`, but when I try to do it with proxy servers I am able to visit the website without any error. What is the problem here?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a specific end-user issue with a web application.

Answer (score 3):

It may be a DNS issue, but I'm not sure. You can test by following the instructions on this page to temporarily switch to Google's public DNS: https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/

If this helps, then you should speak with your ISP about the DNS that they provide. If not, then I honestly have no clue. But whenever this happens to me, changing DNS usually helps.

Honestly, it could be a lot of issues, everything from an error server-side to your browser borking, the DNS not working right, Internet connection, and so on. At least in my experience; I've encountered the issue many times myself.

I would've posted this as a comment if the system had let me, since it's not technically an "answer" as much as it is a suggestion.

There's another possibility too: your IP could be banned, and NovaMov displays a 404 error message when you connect from that IP instead of a "You've been banned" notice... which is something many websites still do for some obscure reason.

Answer (score -1):

The site may have been previously infected with malware.

After cleaning up such an infection on my own site, I was unaware that the intruders had also altered my .htaccess file in such a way that only visitors who were sending a Referer header were exposed to the malware. Since I had removed the malware, visitors received a 404.

The intruders had altered the .htaccess file so that I, the site owner, would not recognize the infection, since I usually visited my own site by entering the URL, while other visitors came via Google.

It could be that accessing the site via proxy also invokes that part of .htaccess.

Comment: @pnuts Maybe, but I sometimes do. Even though _I_ vote to close, others might vote to keep it open, and in such case it is better to have an answered question, than an unanswered one.